# German stanford parser

Tags: java, parsing, haskell, stanford-nlp

I am using the german version of the [stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) to parse short german sentences into a parse tree. An example:

```
Hallo, mein Name ist Luke.

(ROOT
  (S (ITJ Hallo) ($, ,)
    (NP (PPOSAT mein) (NN Name))
    (VAFIN ist)
    (NP-SB (NE Luke))
    ($. .)))
```

I would like to take this output and use it as input for a Haskell program which would arrange it into a tree structure.

Trying to write a Haskell program that parses this output, or any such output from the german  parser would be hard. Does anyone have any advice for any shortcuts, libraries or the like that would make this easier?

I would appreciate not being told to 'just use Java'.

Comment: Writing a Haskell parser for S-expressions is not hard. See e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing

Comment: Wie geht's? Writing parsers is indeed fun (and the link above looks good). Your problem is parsing the string output, right? How are you interfacing with stanford? Can't you get a data structure out?

Comment: Sehr gut! Yes, you are right. The interface with the parser is simply a text file so far...it seems if I know all the tags (ROOT,S,ITJ,...,etc.) then I can treat the string like S-expressions as directed from the previous comment. Thanks @MikhailGlushenkov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally suggested library for these things is parsec. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec